# Share Text + URL via WhatsApp

Tags: android, android-intent, share, whatsapp

I would like to **share text and URL** via WhatsApp.

I have looked into few links, but it has only share text feature.

**How can i share URL + Text ?**

Here is what i have tried so far.

```
Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The text you wanted to share");
try {
    activity.startActivity(whatsappIntent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    ToastHelper.MakeShortText("Whatsapp have not been installed.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "this my text https://www.google.co.in/webhp?ei=6cLkV8utKMnp0ASg5L7oAw&yv=2&rct=j");
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old but concatenating the url (as text) to the text simply works for me